# loading data from hdfs into hive results null output in the table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to load the data from HDFS into hive data warehouse using hive serialization and deserialization query but while retrieving from the table results null output.

Can any one please help me out?

```
hive>create table stations(usaf string, wban string, name string)
    >row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    >with SERDEPROPERTIES(
    >"input.regex" ="(\\d{6}) (\\d{5}) (.{29}) .*"
    >);

hive> load data inpath '/user/cloudera/input-new/ncdc/metadata/stations-fixed-width.txt'
    >into table stations;
```

While retrieving from table

```
   hive>select * from stations limit 4;
```

Results:

```
   NULL NULL NULL
   NULL NULL NULL
   NULL NULL NULL
```

Sample data look like this:

```
010014 99999 SOERSTOKKEN                   NO NO    ENSO  +59783 +005350 +00500
```

Answer (score 1):

checked ur [regex](http://rubular.com/)   -  it's correct only.
Just
Add **output.format.string** in **SERDEPROPERTIES** as  follows :

```
create table stations(usaf string, wban string, name string)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
with SERDEPROPERTIES(
"input.regex" ="(\\d{6}) (\\d{5}) (.{29}) .*",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s"
 )
;
```

Plz check the execution trace image [image]

Comment: thanks for your replay, i just updated query and tried but no changes observed..only series of nulls obtained..

Comment: added the execution trace image. plz check and if useful accept the same.